# Should data.table's CJ continue accommodating arguments with duplicate elements?

Tags: r, data.table

(EDIT: @Arun cleaned and fixed up the code below, and has replaced 'CJ' in data.table on R-Forge. Feature request: [#4849; Faster CJ](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=978&aid=4849&group_id=240)  and update on [Why is expand.grid faster than data.table 's CJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948686/why-is-expand-grid-faster-than-data-table-s-cj))

In my mind `CJ` is meant to work on argument vectors that satisfy `anyDuplicated(vector) == F`.

Does anyone use it with non-unique arguments?

If so, is it worth leveling a 100x speed hit on what I consider to be the primary use?

Lower bound of speed improvement by tuning for primary use (lower bound for these sample arguments, not lower bound for any arguments):

### Comparison:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                  expr        min         lq     median         uq      max neval
    dt1 <- CJ(a, b, c) 3149.15293 3166.59638 3204.95956 3472.70826 4414.919   100
dt2 <- fastCJ(a, b, c)   22.85207   23.16003   23.43691   24.04215 1208.855   100
Output identical: TRUE
```

### Code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

repTE <- function(x, times, each) {
  rep.int(rep.int(x, times=rep.int(each, times=length(x))), times=times)
}
fastCJ <- function(...) {
  arg_list <- list(...)
  l <- lapply(arg_list, sort.int, method="quick")
  seq_ct <- length(l)
  if (seq_ct > 1) {
    seq_lens <- vapply(l, length, numeric(1))
    tot_len <- prod(seq_lens)

    l <-lapply(
      seq_len(seq_ct),
      function(i) {
        if (i==1) {
          len <- seq_lens[1]
          rep.int(l[[1]], times=rep.int(tot_len/len, len))
        } else if (i < seq_ct) {
          pre_len <- prod(seq_lens[1:(i - 1)])
          repTE(l[[i]], times=pre_len, each=tot_len/pre_len/seq_lens[i])
        } else {
          rep.int(l[[seq_ct]], times=tot_len/seq_lens[seq_ct])
        }
      }
    )    
  } else {
    tot_len <- length(l[[1]])
  }

  setattr(l, "row.names", .set_row_names(tot_len))
  setattr(l, "class", c("data.table", "data.frame"))
  if (is.null(names <- names(arg_list))) {
    names <- vector("character", seq_ct)
  }
  if (any(tt <- names == "")) {
    names[tt] <- paste0("V", which(tt))
  }
  setattr(l, "names", names)
  data.table:::settruelength(l, 0L)
  l <- alloc.col(l)
  setattr(l, "sorted", names(l))

  return(l)
}

a <- factor(sample(1:1000, 1000))
b <- sample(letters, 26)
c <- runif(100)
print(microbenchmark( dt1 <- CJ(a, b, c), dt2 <- fastCJ(a, b, c)))
cat("Output identical:", identical(dt1, dt2))
```

Comment: do you have a `seq_list` in your environment somewhere?  ;)

Comment: This seems more like a question for the data.table mailing list, where development issues for the package are discussed.

Comment: Your code, as Ricardo mentions, gives an error with `seq_list` not found. I've managed to get it to work by removing the dependency on `seq_list`. What do you mean using CJ with unique/non-unique arguments? Your code seems to work when there are duplicated elements.. just the order is different.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - Thanks fixed that. Rookie mistake ;)

Comment: @joran - Thanks, I'll find and post there - should I also pull this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about opinions about design/tradeoffs of an existing package.

Comment: @SeanG I think you should leave the question (which will likely be closed) and add a mailing list link later on

Comment: @Arun - It kind of works when there are duplicated elements, but operations downstream may not like that it lies about being keyed properly.

Comment: Please can you check the changes, and acknowledgements to you in NEWS are appropriate. You are very welcome to join the project and make changes yourself!

Comment: @SeanG, probably you should mark this one as answered?

Comment: Sorry, I need to look in to notification settings -- didn't see any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, to add an answer, from [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> CJ() is 90% faster on 1e6 rows (for example), #4849. The inputs are now sorted first before combining rather than after combining and uses rep.int instead of rep (thanks to Sean Garborg for the ideas, code and benchmark) and only sorted if is.unsorted(), #2321.
>
> Reminder: CJ = Cross Join; i.e., joins to all combinations of its inputs.