# Adding extra time points to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has patients "ID", "TIME", "DV", "AMT", "EVID: event ID", "MDV: missing DV" and several patients covariates as below.

```
df
ID    TIME   DV   AMT   MDV   EVID   WT   SEX
9010   0     NA    50    1      1    70    0
9010   0.5   0.2   0     0      0    70    0
9010   1     5     0     0      0    70    0
9010   5     10    0     0      0    70    0
9011   0     NA    50    1      1    60    1
9011   1     4     0     0      0    60    1
9011   3     6     0     0      0    60    1
9011   6     10    0     0      0    60    1
```

I need to add a **unique** "TIME" sequence for each subject ID in addition to the times included in the "df".

```
timeseq <- c(seq(0.05,5,by=0.1))
```

For the rows of added times, "DV=NA; AMT=0; MDV=0; EVID=0". The "ID ; WT; SEX" should stay the same.

I need help in how to add these extra time points to my data frame using R. I have huge dataset and the sampling times points are different between subjects.

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate, you just need to merge against all the possible combinations of `ID` and `TIME` - e.g.: `merge(df,expand.grid(ID=unique(df$ID),TIME=timeseq),by=c("ID","TIME"),all=TRUE)`

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you . However, this gives an `NA` for the other columns!

Comment: See my answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948686/why-is-expand-grid-faster-than-data-table-s-cj) and the comment from @thelatemail, you can use data.table solution since you claim to have a huge set (this will be faster):

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo) #na.locf
dt<-as.data.table(df)
index<-CJ(ID=unique(dt$ID),TIME=timeseq)
gg<-merge(dt,index,by=c("ID","TIME"),all=TRUE)

 gg[!TIME %in% dt$TIME, `:=`(AMT=0,MDV=0,EVID=0)][,`:=`(WT=na.locf(WT),SEX=na.locf(SEX)),by=ID]
       ID TIME DV AMT MDV EVID WT SEX
  1: 9010 0.00 NA  50   1    1 70   0
  2: 9010 0.05 NA   0   0    0 70   0
  3: 9010 0.15 NA   0   0    0 70   0
  4: 9010 0.25 NA   0   0    0 70   0
  5: 9010 0.35 NA   0   0    0 70   0
 ---                                 
104: 9011 4.65 NA   0   0    0 60   1
105: 9011 4.75 NA   0   0    0 60   1
106: 9011 4.85 NA   0   0    0 60   1
107: 9011 4.95 NA   0   0    0 60   1
108: 9011 6.00 10   0   0    0 60   1
```

## data

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(9010L, 9010L, 9010L, 9010L, 9011L, 9011L, 
9011L, 9011L), TIME = c(0, 0.5, 1, 5, 0, 1, 3, 6), DV = c(NA, 
0.2, 5, 10, NA, 4, 6, 10), AMT = c(50L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), MDV = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EVID = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), WT = c(70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L), SEX = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"TIME", "DV", "AMT", "MDV", "EVID", "WT", "SEX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code for the locf gives me an error: Error: `unexpected ']' in gg[!TIME etc`. Is this line of code missing something? @user227710

Comment: @Amer: It runs without an error. May be you incorrectly copy pasted.Every opening `[` will have closing `]`.

Comment: I have it exactly as written. It is strange that it is not working with me. I have many other columns in the data but I think it has nothing to do with these?

Comment: Can you copy paste the code here? I will check what is going on.It doesn't matter how many columns you have.

Comment: Yes. `df <- gg[!TAD%in%ORG.data$TAD,`:=`(AMT=0,MDV=0,EVID=0)][,`:=`(WEIGHT=na.locf(WEIGHT),by=ID2]`

Comment: I have the time as `TAD` and ID as `ID2`. my original data is `ORG.data`

Comment: The code for merging is this: `timeseq <- c(seq(0,5,by=0.1))
 index <- CJ(ID2=unique(ORG.data$ID2),TAD=timeseq)
 gg <- merge(ORG.data,index,by=c("ID2","TAD"),all=TRUE)`

Comment: Yep. You are missing `)` here: `(WEIGHT=na.locf(WEIGHT)` which should be `(WEIGHT=na.locf(WEIGHT))`. The opening `(` needs closing `)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82440/discussion-between-amer-and-user227710).