# How do I stop merge from converting characters into factors?

Tags: r

E.g.

```
chr <- c("a", "b", "c")
intgr <- c(1, 2, 3)
str(chr)
str(base::merge(chr,intgr, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

gives:

```
> str(base::merge(chr,intgr, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
 $ y: num  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

I originally thought it has something to do with how merge coerces arguments into data frames. However, I thought that adding the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` would override the default coercion behaviour of char -> factor, yet this is not working.

**EDIT**: Doing the following gives me expected behaviour:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(base::merge(chr,intgr))
```

that is:

```
> str(base::merge(chr,intgr))
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: chr  "a" "b" "c" "a" ...
 $ y: num  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

but this is not ideal as it changes the global `stringsAsFactors` setting.

Comment: What does `class(chr)` and `class(intgr)` show you?  I have never seen `stringsAsFactors` used with `merge()`.

Comment: `> class(chr)
[1] "character"`, and `> class(intgr)
[1] "numeric`

Comment: i saw that link @Hack-R but it does not apply here: in the case referenced the person is joining two data frames `x, y` with a common column name, except one is a factor and the other a character. Here I am doing the cross product.

Comment: @Alex I see, you're right. So now that you figured out how to get the expected behavior you still want to know what's going on under the hood just out of curiosity? I haven't done this myself but have you considered stepping through the source of the `merge` function to figure it out?

Comment: how do i see the code of `merge`? it looks like an internal function to me? Yes, I think the reason is something to do with factor coercion in the data frame call. I would like to know how to stop this from happening.

Comment: @Alex - `merge.data.frame` ultimately I think, as `merge.default` converts the inputs to `data.frame`'s and then this will call `merge.data.frame`

Comment: @Alex yea `merge.data.frame` or `merge.default`

Comment: `merge.default` tells us exactly what is happening. I don't think we can change the behaviour, in this case, unless the merge.default method changes. I will happily accept this as an answer if you post it: `function (x, y, ...) 
merge(as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y), ...)
<bytecode: 0x000000001b912ba0>
<environment: namespace:base>`

Comment: I'm actually genuinely confused why this doesn't work. `merge.data.frame` has `...` on input, as does `as.data.frame`, which does the conversion of the two input vectors to data.frames. Not sure why the `stringsAsFactors` doesn't get passed through.

Comment: because `merge.default` only calls `as.data.frame(x)` without passing the extra argument. Personally I think this is very undesirable behaviour.

Comment: @Alex - I see, apparently doing `f <- function (x, y, ...) merge(as.data.frame(x,...), as.data.frame(y,...), ...)` and then `f(chr,intgr,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` solves it. I didn't think that would have had to be explicit, but there you go.

Comment: `merge(I(chr),intgr)`

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this particular "merge" using [`expand.grid()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expand.grid.html), since you're really just taking the cartesian product. This allows you to pass the `stringsAsFactors` argument:

```
sapply(expand.grid(x=chr,y=intgr,stringsAsFactors=F),class);
##           x           y
## "character"   "numeric"
```

---

Here's a way of working around this limitation of `merge()`:

```
sapply(merge(data.frame(x=chr,stringsAsFactors=F),intgr),class);
##           x           y
## "character"   "numeric"
```

I would argue that it never makes sense to pass an atomic vector to [`merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html), since it is only really designed for merging data.frames.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `CJ` from `data.table` as welll

```
library(data.table)
str(CJ(chr, intgr))
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  9 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ V1: chr  "a" "a" "a" "b" ...
#$ V2: num  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: this is pretty good, is `CJ` faster than `merge` or `expand.grid`? The other problem with `merge` is how long it is taking.

Comment: @Alex Based on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948686/why-is-expand-grid-faster-than-data-table-s-cj) CJ appears to be faster